# SAS merge if-then getting two results back

Tags: if-statement, merge, sas, unique

I cannot seem to find a way to use and if-then or just an if statement below the unique command in the SAS merge code below. I am matching all of the same S2_Liab numbers just pulling a different number where there is a different title in the "Liability_Lmt" column.

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*---- Additional Partner and/or Corporation charge ----------  
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
data full;
 set whole_FR; 
 record_num=_N_;
 S2_Liab = S2LiabLimit;

run;

proc sort; 
by S2_Liab;
run;

data unique(keep=S2_Liab S2Partners P_charge FD_charge); 
 set WORK.FR_S2_Mandatory_Liab_Cov; 
 S2_Liab = Liability_Lmt;

if Additional = "Partner_Corp" then P_charge = round(&thestate.,0.01);
if Additional = "Farm_Dwelling" then FD_charge = round(&thestate.,0.01);

run;

proc sort nodupkey; 
by S2_Liab;
run;

data match nonmatch; 
 merge full(in=a) unique(in=b);

 by S2_Liab;
 if a=1 and b=1 then output match;
 if a=1 and b=0 then output nonmatch;
 run;

data whole_FR;
 set match nonmatch;

proc sort;
 by record_num;
run;
```

---

For the first if-then statement above I am getting no results, instead the code seems to skip directly to the second if-then statement.

These are my results show me all of the numbers for the second if statement ("FD_charge") but blank answers for "P_charge". For some reason the program skips over the first if statement and prints out the answer for the second if statement. I have also tried an if-then-else statement but I get the same answers.

Does anybody have a clue how to make this work?

Comment: This sounds like it's something specific to your data.  SAS is certainly not 'skipping' your if statement; it is not finding any identical matches.  There are a lot of potential reasons for that, including not having any matches, having different lengths for your variables, etc.  Does your log give you any information?

Comment: The log doesn't say anything that would help. I know the data matches the first set that it is now 'skipping' because I tested that batch of data first and then added the second if statement.

Comment: Then you're missing something, or something changed that you aren't aware of.  SAS does not skip if statements, and from a programming point of view that data step is fine.

Comment: Replace nodupkey with (proc means noprint;
    by S2_Liab;
    output out=unique(drop=_type_ _freq_) sum=;
    run;) This treats the columns like a pivot table in excel. My program was not "Skipping" is was just grabbing the first number for the first row name.